# A more general word for "nationalism"

Tags: word-request

Not the patriotism, but more-so the dominating aspect, the desire to conquer and to have territorial control. An insufficiency of power or domination.

Comment: The question is rather a hodge-podge.  I'm voting to close because the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that would be called [**imperialism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperialism). But imperialism does not necessarily have to revolve around one particular ethic group (the term *ethnic group* is a little bit different from the term *nation* since *nation* is more of a political concept) that wants to conquer and dominate others based on cultural or ethic differences. The following passage is what the Wikipedia article on *imperialism* has to say about it:

> Imperialism is an action that involves a nation extending its power by the acquisition of inhabited territory. It may also include the exploitation of these territories, an action that is linked to colonialism. Colonialism is generally regarded as an expression of imperialism.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what context you are trying to use the word in but possibly **CONQUEST** is what you want. Or **CRUSADER**